# Distributing a web crawler in Python

Tags: python, web-crawler, distributed-computing

I'm a Python learner and I've been really getting into this article:

["A Web Crawler With asyncio Coroutines" by A. Jesse Jiryu Davis and Guido van Rossum](http://aosabook.org/en/500L/a-web-crawler-with-asyncio-coroutines.html)

One thing I don't understand is how I would grow this program over a cluster of several computers.  Is that a part of the asyncio library or are you sort of "on your own" for the distributed piece?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to use an external task queue. There are many to choose from, [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) is a popular one. The basic idea is that you push jobs onto a queue, where any number of worker processes can consume them. For a web crawler, a job could be as simple as a URL to grab. Workers would grab a URL from the queue, retrieve it, parse it, and add any new URLs to the queue as new jobs.

The advantage of this system is that workers are just processes, and can communicate with the queue across a network, so you can have as many workers, on as many machines, as you like.